# Ext JS 4 radio group check event

Tags: extjs, radio-button, radio-group, ext4

I am creating a radioGroup in extJS 4 using xtype inside a FormPanel. I am trying to enable/disable a textfield as soon as the radio is checked.

```
{
xtype: 'radiogroup',
fieldLabel: 'Enable / Disable ',
columns: 2,
vertical: true,
items: [
     {boxLabel: 'Enable', name: 'formtype', inputValue: '1'},
     {boxLabel: 'Disable', name: 'formtype', inputValue:'2',checked:true},
    ]
 }
```

I am confused where to add the listeners for check/click event. Thanks a ton in advance.

Comment: I tried to add this way but why the its showing the alert() for 2 times?

Comment: listeners: {
    "change" : function(field, newValue, oldValue, eOpts ){
    alert(this.items);
   }
        }

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to handle 'change' event on every radio button. When a radio button changes (selected) then enable/disable the textfield.

Following an example:

```
Ext.create ('Ext.container.Container', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody () ,
    items: [{
        xtype: 'textfield' ,
        id: 'tf' ,
        disabled: true ,
        fieldLabel: 'My Text'
    } , {
        xtype: 'radiogroup',
        fieldLabel: 'Enable / Disable ',
        columns: 2,
        vertical: true,
        items: [{
            boxLabel: 'Enable',
            name: 'formtype' , 
            inputValue: '1' ,
            listeners: {
                change: function (cb, nv, ov) {
                    if (nv) Ext.getCmp('tf').enable ();
                }
            }
        } , {
            boxLabel: 'Disable', 
            name: 'formtype', 
            inputValue:'2',
            checked: true ,
            listeners: {
                change: function (cb, nv, ov) {
                    if (nv) Ext.getCmp('tf').disable ();
                }
            }
        }]
    }]
});
```

Ciao

Answer (score 2):

If you set your listener change event on the radio group itself (not on each button) you will only have to handle one event.  Your listener/handler will be called and passed `newVal` and `oldVal`.  You can then grab the `newVal` as the value that was selected.